# How to integrate the following sum?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

I'm currently trying to show:
$$
\int_0^1{\int_0^y{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10^{n+1}x(1-x)}\left(9+\frac{1}{1-x^{10^n}}-\frac{10}{1-x^{10^{n+1}}}\right)\right)dx}dy}=\frac{10}{99}\log(10)
$$
What I have tried so far is to manipulate the sum; I arrived at:
\begin{align}
&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{10^{n+1}x(1-x)}\left(9+\frac{1}{1-x^{10^n}}-\frac{10}{1-x^{10^{n+1}}}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac{10}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{99}{10}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}{\frac{x^{r10^n+k-1}}{10^n}}\\
&=\frac{10}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{99}{10}\sum_{s=1}^{\infty}{x^{s-1}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{10^n}\left\lfloor\frac{s}{10^n}\right\rfloor}}
\end{align}
which should be fairly easy to integrate, but every time I do it, I obtain a different result, but never $\frac{10}{99}\log(10)$. I even checked the series I got; they seem to agree numerically.

How can the result be proven? Preferably, I would like to see an answer in which one of the series above is integrated, but all proofs are appreciated.